# Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure - kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have created a demo from here : https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker

Done same as explained over there.

Added Api key also in my Manifest file as below inside application tag:

```
            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="secret_api_key_not_shown"/>
```

Getting below error :

> E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
>   12-05 16:22:30.108 10392-10522/com.mypackage E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
>       Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Comment: Hide your api key when ever you paste your code in public forums.

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard visit this and under "Library" enable google maps api.

Comment: Have you enabled Google Map Native api from google developer console ?

Comment: @PrashantSable it's dummy value. changed. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @PrashantSable For Integrating it, We need to enable MAPS SDK for Android. Same if it's in the case of IOS, we have to enable MAPS SDK for IOS. Solved. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the "[Maps SDK for Android](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/maps-android-backend.googleapis.com)" API from the Developer Console.